# Register Page Themeing

Tags: theming, users

I just found out the template for themeing the register page is **page-user-register.tpl.php**.

But, how do I change the labels on the textfields etc?

For instance, I want to rename the **E-Mail** label to ... somethingelse :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good tutorial to change all the user pages.  http://drupal.org/node/350634.   For E-Mail edit the $variable['form']['x']

Comment: Thanks, iStryker but can you tell me how to discover the value of 'x'       (according to your code) in my form?

Answer (score 1):

Another route to take: Use the code below in the template.php file of your theme.  Be sure to change "YOURTHEME" to the name of your theme.  If `YOURTHEME_theme()` already exists you need to add to the returned array.  Change "Something Else" to whatever you want the label to be and **clear the cache** or you won't see the changes.

```
function YOURTHEME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'user_register' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' = NULL),
    ),
  );
}

function YOURTHEME_user_register($form) {
  $form['mail']['#title'] = t('Something Else');

  return drupal_render($form);
}
```